# Error occurring while adding new entry in kendo-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am facing issue while adding new entry in kendo-grid. The data is getting saved, but giving an error like below :

**The default edit service of the editing directives works only when binding to plain array.Please provide an editService.**

Even google is unable to say any answer for this particularly.

The below is my html :

```
<kendo-grid-command-column width="70">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-isNew="isNew" let-dataItem="dataItem">
        <button kendoGridEditCommand type="button" [disabled]="HasProcessed" (click)="editCustomDednDetails(dataItem)" [primary]="true">
            <img src="/FinTechApp/assets/images/ico_edit.png">
        </button>
        <button type="button" kendoGridRemoveCommand [disabled]="HasProcessed" *ngIf="!dataItem.IsInEditMode" (click)="fnDeletecustomdeductionDetails(dataItem.EmpMonthlyCustomDeductionDetailsId)">
            <img src="/FinTechApp/assets/images/ico_delete.png">
        </button>
        <button kendoGridSaveCommand type="button" (click)="fnUpdateEmpCustomDednDetails(dataItem)">
            {{ isNew ? '' : '' }}
            <img src="/FinTechApp/assets/images/ico_save.png" title="Add">
        </button>
        <button kendoGridCancelCommand type="button">
            {{ isNew ? '' : '' }}
            <img src="/FinTechApp/assets/images/ico_cancel.png" title="Cancel">
        </button>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-command-column>
```

And below is the edit button command I am using :

```
editCustomDednDetails(data) {
    var CustomDeductionObj: CustomDeduction = data;
    CustomDeductionObj.IsInEditMode = true;
    this.SelectedDedHead = new DeductionHeads();
    this.SelectedDedHead.DeductionHeadId = data.DeductionHeadId;
    this.finTechService.OperationType = PageAccessType.Edit;
}
```

Feel free to ask any question. I am really in a big mess.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ispostback....how you are using CustomDeductionObj futher in your code to save data?

Comment: Only in the edit functionality provided above...no where else